# Central worksheet that distributes content to other worksheets based on certain criteria

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a macro that can transfer rows of data to a different worksheet depending on a certain value from that row. For example, I have the following data in a central worksheet, Masterlog.xls:

(a hyphen denotes a column)

Apples - 12312312

Green Apples - 32132132

Mangoes - 00000000

Green Mangoes - 11111111

Bananas - 22222222

The masterlog data is updated daily and manually by 2 people. Sometimes the data is a duplicate of yesterday's and I was also hoping for a macro that ignores duplicates and remembers data from 2 days ago but clears data that is older.

Column A's value will determine which worksheet the row of data will go to.

Apples - 12312312 should be transferred to the Worksheet Apples.xls

Green Apples - 32132132 is also transferred to Apples.xls on the next row.

Mangoes - 00000000 goes to Mangoes.xls and so on.

The macro should always write on the first empty row after the last one with content.

The Apples.xls, Mangoes.xls and Bananas.xls are shared worksheets with 22 users.

Comment: Hi @Alex4336, no, I have not tried anything yet. I do not know how to write code from scratch...

Comment: Please someone help... Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will do the trick of copying the data to the appropriate sheet. It doesn't clear the sheets beforehand, meaning that if you run the macro multiple times, it will add the same entries after the entries already there, but it should give you a palce to start.

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()

Dim col As New Collection, cell As Range, ChkRng As Range, entry As Variant, lstRw As Long, i As Long

With Sheets("Masterlog")
    Set ChkRng = .Range("A4:A" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
End With

On Error Resume Next

For Each cell In ChkRng
    If col.Count = 0 Then GoTo Add
        For i = 1 To col.Count
            If cell.Value Like "*" & col.Item(i) Then
                GoTo continue
            End If
        Next i
Add:
            col.Add cell.Value, cell.Value



continue:

Next cell
On Error GoTo 0

For Each cell In ChkRng
    For i = 1 To col.Count



            If cell.Value = col.Item(i) Then
                If WorksheetExists(col.Item(i)) = False Then
                    Worksheets.Add , Sheets("Masterlog")
                    ActiveSheet.Name = col.Item(i)
                    With Sheets(col.Item(i))
                        lstRw = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                        .Range("A" & lstRw) = cell.Value
                        .Range("A" & lstRw).Offset(0, 1) = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                    End With
                Else
                    With Sheets(col.Item(i))
                        lstRw = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                        .Range("A" & lstRw) = cell.Value
                        .Range("A" & lstRw).Offset(0, 1) = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                    End With
                End If
                GoTo onwards
            ElseIf cell.Value Like "*" & col.Item(i) = True Then
                If WorksheetExists(col.Item(i)) = False Then
                        Worksheets.Add , Sheets("Masterlog")
                        ActiveSheet.Name = col.Item(i)
                    With Sheets(col.Item(i))
                        lstRw = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                        .Range("A" & lstRw) = cell.Value
                        .Range("A" & lstRw).Offset(0, 1) = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                    End With
                Else
                    With Sheets(col.Item(i))
                        lstRw = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                        .Range("A" & lstRw) = cell.Value
                        .Range("A" & lstRw).Offset(0, 1) = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                    End With
                End If
                GoTo onwards
            End If


    Next i
onwards:
Next cell

End Sub

Public Function WorksheetExists(ByVal WorksheetName As String) As Boolean

On Error Resume Next
WorksheetExists = (Sheets(WorksheetName).Name <> "")
On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

Currently it transfers both the value in Column A and the value in Column B, but you should change that to your needs.

It works for your example. I don't know about more complicated patterns.

Comment: Hi thank you for this. This is something that I can work with. What if instead of different worksheets, make it different workbooks? Is this a big change in code? Thank you so much @Alex4336

Comment: This is working! Just a few edits and I guess this will be perfect! Thank you for this! I have a follow up question though, what if instead of different worksheets, make it different workbooks? Is this a big change in code? Thank you so much @Alex4336

Comment: It is certainly possible to make it for different workbooks, but I think that it will require opening the specific workbook, if it exist, or otherwise create one, at a folder of your choice ofc.